# How do I get Google Sheets to repeat data in a cell X times?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm a Google Sheet newbie so appreciate any help. I would like to get the names I have in a cell to repeat X amount of times down a column and have it repeat for the following names that I have. I'm not really sure where to start.

Here is an example of what I'd like to do: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aCEi3uo1xztZM6FiXvo6_MW84d9wbawcxJ8NMJFP4aE/edit#gid=0

Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: Hi @rainbowx44, have you tried using the `REPT` & `TRANSPOSE` functions for this task?

Comment: @ale13 - I'm not familiar with those functions but I can try it out!

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1

You can use this formula:

```
={INDEX(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A6,B1)," "))),0,1);INDEX(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A6,B1)," "))),0,2);INDEX(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A6,B1)," "))),0,3);INDEX(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A6,B1)," "))),0,4);INDEX(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A6,B1)," "))),0,5);INDEX(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:A6,B1)," "))),0,6)}
```

This one makes use of the below formulas:

- `REPT` for repeating the data `B1` times;
- `SPLIT` for splitting the data;
- `TRANSPOSE` for transposing the resulting rows;
- `INDEX` for merging the resulting columns into a single one;

**Note**

A blank space has been added after each name in order to make splitting easier and more convenient.

After the formula is being applied, this is how it will look like:

[image: result formula]

#### Method 2

You can make use of Apps Script - Apps Script is a powerful development platform which can be used to build web apps and automate tasks. What makes it special is the fact that it is easy to use and to create applications that integrate with G Suite.

Therefore, your task can be accomplished by using this script:

```
function multiplyValues() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_OF_THE_SPREADSHEET").getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
   var rangeVals = ss.getRange("A1:A6");
   var nameValues = rangeVals.getValues();
   var multValue = ss.getRange("B1").getValue();
   var arrayVals = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < nameValues.length; i++)
      for (var j = 1; j <= multValue; j++) 
         arrayVals.push(nameValues[i][0]);

   for (var i = 0; i < arrayVals.length; i++) 
      ss.getRange(i+1, 4).setValue(arrayVals[i]);
}
```

**Explanation**

The above script is bulding the array by multiplying each value with the value from the `B1` cell and afterwards is pasting its contents on the 4th column. In order to get the values the `getRange` and `getValues` methods have been used and to paste the new array in the column the `setValue` has been used.

[image: script result]

#### Reference

I also recommend you to take a look at the links below since they might be of help to you.

- [TRANSPOSE function Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en);
- [REPT function Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134?hl=en);
- [INDEX function Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en);
- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column);
- [Range Class Apps Script - getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues);
- [Range Class Apps Script - setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).

Comment: Consider moving your answer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73880042/repeat-whole-row-n-times-based-on-column-value-in-google-sheets) for better exposure.