# Repeat whole row N times based on column value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, repeat

Input:

```
Order No    Textbook    Grade       Time          No of times to be repeated
1234        Biology       6      16:30-17:30               2
1235        Physics       7      20:00-21:00               3
```

Desired Output:-

```
1234        Biology       6      16:30-17:30
1234        Biology       6      16:30-17:30
1235        Physics       7      20:00-21:00
1235        Physics       7      20:00-21:00
1235        Physics       7      20:00-21:00
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-sheets-formula/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: Reopened. The duplicate probably needs reversal. Rationale: The strategy mentioned in the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70160891/how-to-repeat-a-data-set-several-columns-x-times-in-google-sheets) is similar to the strategy in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73880367). There is another answer(mine) providing a different strategy altogether. It is better if this question is made canonical rather than the older one.

Answer (score 2):

##### Input:

| Order | No | Textbook | Grade | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Biology | 6 | 16:30-17:30 | 3 |
| 1235 | Physics | 7 | 20:00-21:00 | 1 |

##### Solution:

Use `SEQUENCE` to create a loop  returning the current row for each iteration. The loop is accomplished through `REDUCE`:

```
=REDUCE(A1:D1,E2:INDEX(E:E,COUNTA(E:E)),
  LAMBDA(a,c,
    LAMBDA(row,
      {
        a;
        IF(c > 1,
          REDUCE(row,SEQUENCE(c-1),LAMBDA(a_,c_,{a_;row})),
          row
        )
      }
    )(OFFSET(c,0,-4,1,4))
  )
)
```

##### Output:

| Order | No | Textbook | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Biology | 6 | 16:30-17:30 |
| 1234 | Biology | 6 | 16:30-17:30 |
| 1234 | Biology | 6 | 16:30-17:30 |
| 1235 | Physics | 7 | 20:00-21:00 |

##### Advantage:

No more string manipulation and emojis

Comment: `REDUCE(A1:D1,` can it be replaced with `SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(A1:S1)...)`? I'll test it after few moments

Comment: @Osm No. Those are headers: `Order  No  Textbook  Grade`. If you replace them, then they will be numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(JOIN("",INDEX(REPT(BYROW(A2:D3,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("|",0,x)))&"@",E2:E3))),"@")),"|"))
```

[image]

To make it dynamic spill array, use-

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(JOIN("",INDEX(REPT(BYROW(A2:INDEX(D2:D,MATCH("zzz",D2:D)),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("|",0,x)))&"@",E2:INDEX(E2:E,MATCH(9^9,E2:E))))),"@")),"|"))
```

[image]

Comment: `INDEX`,  and  `MATCH(9^9` seems to solve alot of problems.

Comment: For dynamic row reference in a column, it works like magic.

Comment: @Osm Always recommended  [`INDEX/COUNTA`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884012/) instead of `IF(A:A="",,)` for ages.

Comment: @TheMaster `COUNTA` will work good when data in a column is continuous. In case of blank rows in a column then have data after few rows, use of match will detect last row.

Comment: @Harun24hr I am aware of that and did mention it in my  linked answer. That is the minor disadvantage. Advantage is you don't need to know the type of data -number or text, whereas with `MATCH`, you need to. I also believe `COUNT`(numeric operations in general) operation is faster than `MATCH`.

Comment: @TheMaster I am totally agree with you.