# Google sheets - How get multiple rows from one row by number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, repeat

please, I don't know what to do. I want to get (create) rows in Google Sheets from other row by number in this row. From other tab or diferent sheet.

For example: Create the second table from the first table.
I tried Query and Sequence, but I guess I don't have that skill.
Formula ideally based on "query".

1)

| Code | PCS | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | 2 | DataA |
| Product2 | 1 | DataB |
| Product3 | 0 | DataC |
| Product4 | 4 | DataD |

2)

| Code | PCS | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | 2 | DataA |
| Product1 | 2 | DataA |
| Product2 | 1 | DataB |
| Product4 | 4 | DataD |
| Product4 | 4 | DataD |
| Product4 | 4 | DataD |
| Product4 | 4 | DataD |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat whole row N times based on column value in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73880042/repeat-whole-row-n-times-based-on-column-value-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=index(query({A1,B1,C1;
iferror(flatten(if(B2:B<>"",split(rept(A2:A&"|",B2:B),"|"),)),),
iferror(flatten(if(B2:B<>"",split(rept(B2:B&"|",B2:B),"|"),)),),
iferror(flatten(if(B2:B<>"",split(rept(C2:C&"|",B2:B),"|"),)),)
},"where Col1 is not null",1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT("‍"&FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:B>0; A2:C&"​"; ));;9^9)); B2:B); "‍")); "​"); "where Col3 is not null"; ))
```

[image]